# Make an XML that has 6 imagebuttons

Tags: android, xml, imagebutton

I want to create an UI that has 6 ImageButton, whenever i tap on the image i have an Activity that is triggered.
How to make this UI in XML. Any idea please.
[ I already know how to create a selector for each ImageButton]
Image example: http://lh3.ggpht.com/RYB2ckycDc_4rb2bmsDzqLLmYcj37xDOA7d7sR6XIVfwRb3a44_HqMqfb1vdmtxTEidenVY4C9RcTREl

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use relative layout.......you can also use gridview if you wish...

Comment: In relative layout can i control the resolution of the image? I already maked 2 imagebutton and have the left one taking almost the whole first line(touches the second button).

Comment: Is the GridView can resize each image button automatically? And how to code a listener in each image in GridView ? Thanks

Comment: you can not control resolution with relative layout but your alignment will be easy....

Comment: check this for gridview   http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html

Comment: So what do you suggest to use in my case. Simple imagebutton or gridview ?